# Change the font size for the the browser tree in pgAdmin4?

Tags: pgadmin

The font size can be changed for sql editor in preferences. Is there a way to change the font size of the browser tree in the left frame?

Answer (score 4):

As of pgAdmin4 v5.1 there is a *File > Runtime* menu that allows you to zoom in and out, which will affect all fonts in pgAdmin.

Comment: works!! as there are different +/- keymapping, this and only this menue entry fixes that issue! thx!

Answer (score 2):

**pgAdmin4** starts his own webserver accessible at `http://127.0.0.1:34809/browser/`

From there you can easily change font size with usual browser options as <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>.

Comment: this port isn't fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Make a text file called 'qt.conf' with the following contents:

```
[Platforms]
WindowsArguments = dpiawareness=0
```

Then put this in your pgAdmin folder, e.g. `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\pgAdmin 4\bin` and re-run pgAdmin.

Source: https://georgik.rocks/how-to-increase-font-size-in-pgadmin-4-on-windows/

Answer (score 1):

You can just use CTRL +/- to adjust font size, on the fly. It works fine for PGAdmin 4 v6.0.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you could use `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` environment variable. And eventually `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR` to adjust.

So the following command should work from console:

```
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5                     ## or any number
pgadmin4
```

Else:

```
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0           ## as boolean
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.5                     ## as float
pgadmin4
```

source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Qt_5

Comment: Neither one of these worked for me with Ubuntu 22.04 (running the traditional Xorg display server). What made a difference was enabling "Large Fonts" in system accessibility options.